How sandwich transactions are still alive
I’ve been researching MEV(especially frontrunning and backrunning) after the moment I came across this account
https://solscan.io/account/D4zVhwuUsFbcaty7wJhNEZ7VEwPHXQ5d2heXPxM5yWhL?page=4#transfers
I knew about jaredfromsubway.eth before and I know that Ethereum has sort of “public mempool”, which Solana doesn’t
Validators take part in creating and confirming blocks as I understand so my main question, is this account somehow linked with validator or paying him a bribe. This is my only guess how it’s still possible as there is no public Solana mempool where he can find profitable transactions

Take a look at this with a discerning eye.
https://www.jito.network/

So you’re saying, that Jito, which has under control around 1/3 of blocks is using sandwich bots to pay stackers ? Isn’t it like unethical ? Or am I wrong at some point

Pretty much! I wouldn't go so far to say it is unethical, but it definitely makes me not want to partake in the Solana ecosystem as a retail user. If I was a staker, I'd probably choose Jito due to the higher rewards (hence, Jito's hold over many stakers).
